# Error parsing JSON in python

Tags: python, json, parsing, reddit

I'm trying to parse a reddit JSON file to get titles of the posts, however when I use this code:

```
import urllib2
import json

response = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.reddit.com/r/technology/.json')
data = json.load(response)   
print data['title']
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Harry\Desktop\py\jason.py", line 6, in <module>
    print data['title']
KeyError: 'title'
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That response has no `'title'` top-level key. Only `'kind'` and `'data'` keys are found in the top-level dictionary.

You need to look more closely at the structure here; the `data` key contains the actual payload, but that's a dictionary without a `'title'` key as well.

Here is a elided version of the contents:

```
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(data)
{u'data': {u'after': u't3_1wnfuv',
           u'before': None,
           u'children': [{u'data': {u'approved_by': None,
                                    u'author': u'papa00king',
                                    # [...]
                                    # Many keys omitted
                                    # [...]
                                    u'title': u'UK government will unblock websites after adult filter blunder',
                                    u'ups': 1030,
                                    u'url': u'http://www.engadget.com/2014/01/31/uk-government-adult-filter-whitelist/',
                                    u'visited': False},
                          u'kind': u't3'},
                          # [...]
                          # Many many more children
                          # [...]
                          ],
           u'modhash': u''},
 u'kind': u'Listing'}
```

If you are looking for the titles of all the children in the result, use:

```
for child in data['data']['children']:
    print child['data']['title']
```

in other words, each 'object' has `kind` and `data` keys, and a `Listing` kind of object has a `children` key, a list of *more* objects with `kind` and `data` keys. The `t3` kind of objects that you are looking for have `title` keys in the `data` structure.

Demo:

```
>>> for child in data['data']['children']:
...     print child['data']['title']
... 
UK government will unblock websites after adult filter blunder
The upside to being let go by Nokia - Thousands of workers made redundant have set up over 400 new technology companies using grants of up to €20,000 - costing Nokia 'tens of millions of Euro's'
You wouldn't download a car: Honda releases concept car 3D printing files
Could 3D printing provide new solutions for disabled people? - Disabled people often need personalised equipment to help with their individual needs. Could 3D printing provide a cheap and efficient solution?
Five of India's most popular small cars fail their first ever crash tests, showing that they could lead to fatalities or serious injuries if involved in an accident.
Kansas Legislature Wants To Stop Any Other Kansas Cities From Getting Google Fiber
Google’s Latest Moves Toward Scarily Personalized Searches
This $75 synthesizer will turn anything into an instrument
Best Buy slashes price of Surface Pro by $400
This Is What a Computer Sees When It Watches The Matrix
Windows 8.1 update to hide tile interface by default
Young farmers win award for designing cattle management app
IBM's speedy graphene chip could lead to super-efficient mobile devices
South Korea fines Google $196K for illegal data gathering
Microsoft said to be preparing to promote from within, make Satya Nadella next CEO
Pirate Bay ban lifted in Netherlands as blocking torrent sites ruled ‘ineffective’
Haptics, Trackballs and Cheeto Dust: How Valve built the game controller of the future
Icelandic drilling project opens door to volcano-powered electricity
Here's how to know if your Gmail account has been hacked
Amazon considering $20 to $40 price hike for Prime service in US
Massive spending on computing gear underpins Google profits
Yahoo Mail accounts breached, number of affected users not disclosed
AMD (almost) rolls out Mantle, its high performance alternative to Direct3D and OpenGL
Physicists create synthetic magnetic monopole predicted more than 80 years ago
Facebook Is About To Let You Go Anonymous For The First Time
```

Comment: How would I get it to output the title key then?

Comment: @Cephon: **What** title key, there are several.

Comment: if you think data as dictionary, then print data.keys(), you will see all the key